# Power Automate Flow to get specific cells based on user input

Tags: automation, power-automate, power-virtual-agents

I am currently working on a Microsoft Power Virtual Agent (PVA) chatbot that helps users understand complicated documents. Right now I am looking at making a flow that takes a user's zipcode as input and then returns a departments contact information from a Sheet. I am firstly not sure what the best solution is, I am using 'get rows' on a Google Sheet, but I am not sure if I should be using a Sharepoint list instead.

My real issues are the following:
How do I get the right row out based on the zipcode a user provides? So if I give it 2000 as a Zipcode in PVA and turn that into an input for the flow, how does it run through the rows in a sheet and find the right one dynamically, then how do I select that row and turn the other cells that are part of it into variables? I tried to use control loops but could not get that to work right.

I've added a pic here of what I currently have

[image: pic of flow]

Comment: If you can move off Google Sheets to Excel Online (OneDrive/SharePoint) ... I reckon we can get a result for you without much hassle.

Comment: @Skin, fantastic, I've gotten it over into a Sharepoint list now! Any suggestions on how to find the row that I want and what steps to use? My first instinct says Sharepoint 'Get Items', but I am not really sure where to go from there, I am really new to this.

Comment: I meant get the Excel workbook to a SharePoint folder.  :-)  A list will work as well though.  `Get items` can be filtered on each call so you can get just the items you want.  I don't fully follow what you're doing but from a lookup perspective, using a list is a real option.

Comment: @Skin, I want to connect to a Sharepoint List, Excel file or sheet, and based on a zipcode that is in the first column select that row, then get the cells that are in the same row (phonenumber, department name and department website) and assign those to different variables. Then pass those variables back to PVA. I seem to have the connection part under control, what is hard is dynamically finding the row based on input, and looping through the row or items I get to make sure I only get those specific items out.

Comment: Ok, throw it in an Excel spreadsheet on a SharePoint drive and I'll write the office script for you.  You'll need to show an example of your worksheet though so I can replicate it.

Comment: So the user gives a zipcode, scan the first column, and then when the right one is found, remember the row, and pass the cells that include relevant information from only those rows. I'd know how to do that in code with loops etc., but here it's somehow harder for me to get my head around.

Comment: @skin, shall I write in a PM or something? I'd like to avoid uploading anything here publically. And what do you mean by office script? :-)

Comment: Working on it now.  I'll get back to you.

Comment: @Skin, I am not familiar with Office Scripts, so I am not sure how that works with Power Automate and PVA? I'd just hate to waste your time... :-) I thought this was something that could be done in Power Automate Flows

Comment: It is, bear with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and see how you go.

I created an Excel document that stores your zip codes.  You need to store it in a SharePoint online folder, mine looks like this ...

[image: Spreadsheet]

You'll notice that in Excel Online (hopefully you have this, if not, it's a tenancy thing that needs to be activated) you'll have a tab in the ribbon called **Automate** ...

[image: Automate Tab]

In there, create a new script, call it **Zip Code Lookup** and then paste in this code ...

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook, zipCodeToFilter: string)
{
  let activeSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
  let zipCodeRange = activeSheet.getUsedRange();
  let zipCodeValues = zipCodeRange.getValues();

  let zipCodeFilter = zipCodeValues.filter(row => {
    return row[0].toString() == zipCodeToFilter;
  });

  let zipCodeResult: ZipCode = null;

  if (zipCodeFilter.length == 1) {
    zipCodeResult = {
      zipCode: zipCodeFilter[0][0].toString(),
      phoneNumber: zipCodeFilter[0][1].toString(),
      departmenName: zipCodeFilter[0][2].toString(),
      website: zipCodeFilter[0][3].toString()
    }
  }

  return zipCodeResult;
}

interface ZipCode {
  zipCode: string,
  phoneNumber: string,
  departmenName: string,
  website: string
}
```

Now in PowerAutomate, you should be able to include an action called **Run script** which is a part of the **Excel Online (Business)** group of actions.

Here is an example of what I have configured.  Specifically, I'm going to look up zip code **53478** ...

[image: Run Script]

... then when the script runs, you get this output and all of the variables are split out for future use.

[image: Result]

So I can set the department name into a new variable if I need to (but you don't because it's already a dynamic property) ...

[image: Result]

Comment: That worked great. I think I owe you a beer. What can I do to thank you?

Comment: Maybe upvote the answer?  No worries anyway. There were many ways to do what you wanted, that one was a little less involved.

Comment: How would this be amended to return an array to power automate if 2 results were found for the zip code?